# Possible to further factor out a summation of products?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to somehow factor out the equation below such that I have x and y together, and separate from z?

$$\sum_k^n x_k y_k z_k$$

I realize I cannot do

$$\sum_k^n x_k y_k \sum_k^n z_k$$

but not sure if there's anything else possible.

Comment: [Summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) can help.

Comment: @eminem thank you for your comment! sorry, but I'm not sure I see how summation by parts will help here. would you be able to explain a bit please?

Comment: Summation by parts transforms a series of products of sequences into other summations, often simplifying the computation or estimation of certain types of sums. I'm not sure exactly what you want to achive, but it is one of the tools you might use.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do in the general case.  How would you factor $x_1y_1z_1+x_2y_2z_2$?